# Make Multiple Circles In Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am relatively new to photoshop, but have the following task: I must make around 15 black circles with a white number in the middle. Each circle is the same size as every other. I am trying to create vector masks, but it seems hokey. Is there a way that I can:

1. Make 1 circle (preferrably vector) and then make copies of this circle that conform to the same size as the template circle.
2. Make text in each circle that is "bound" to the circle.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. create new layer
2. use the ellipse tool and drag with shift a circle
3. double click on the layer(circle). this opens the layer style
4. check color overlay and choose the color
5. create a new layer
6. open the text tool and type two digits in it
7. center the text with the paragraph tool
8. select the layer with the circle and the layer with the text and align them vertically and horizontally
9. put them into a folder
10. now you can duplicate the folder x-times
11. replace the "digit-placeholder" with the wanted numbers
12. select a folder press v and place them where you want them, x-times

Comment: Thank you sir. And I guess I select all of them at the same time and perform one big resize to resize them all.

Comment: I would add, a final step, before saving, make a copy and then select all of the text and then select Text > Convert to Shape—this will make your text into a vector so it scales.  cheers!